# Powershell constructor not found when run through website

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, iis

Having trouble with a Powershell script that includes a constructor that overrides System.XML. When running the script through the command line, it works fine. The constructor is found and the script completes normally.
We also have it setup to run through a POST request. The user POSTs a URL that resolves to the Powershell script. It was originally set up on Windows 2008 r2. We are moving to Windows 2012 r2.
When running through the URL, we get the following message:

> A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type >LexisNexis.Xml.XmlResolver.

The only difference seems to be that on 2008, we are running Powershell v3, where as on 2012, we are running Powershell v4.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you referencing the `LexisNexis.Xml.XmlResolver` type in PowerShell? `Add-Type` \ Importing a `.dll`? Are you able to provide us with a small example script that generates the error you're experiencing? Off the top of my head you could try explicitly casting the parameters in PowerShell to the types needed for the constructor, PowerShell's type inference might cause it to look for a constructor that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks the reply.
The type definition string is created as $LexisNexisXmlSrc, then this is called:

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies "System.xml" -TypeDefinition $LexisNexisXmlSrc

This is declared in a library file, which we then include as such:

. (Join-Path $includeDir "LexisNexisXml.ps1")